# Android app with backblaze

Tags: android, cloud-storage

I am creating an android app which is consuming REST api that were created in Google App Engine(Java).

I also want to store some images and videos which would be uploaded by users when they will use my app.

I was looking for best place to store that data and after some surfing i came across Backblaze, but am not able to find any tutorials, is backblaze used only to backup data or can it work with codes also?

Comment: All you need is a generic file server with upload functionality. In other words, you need to find a Virtual Private Server, or VPS.

Comment: Looks like Backblaze [offers a web API](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/). They even have sample code at the end of each doc page.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear there is an (unofficial?) [Java library](https://github.com/oliverdunk/JB2) that you can use with Backblaze.

It does say it requires Java 8, which Android doesn't do, so you'll need to download it as a Maven project and build using Java 6 or 7 with `mvn package` and add it as a dependency to your project. You'll probably need to fix some Java 8 specific things also, if they are used in that code.

Example code from the README

```
B2Session session = B2API.authorizeAccount("accountID", "applicationKey");

//Create the Bucket
B2Bucket bucket = B2API.createBucket(session, "ExampleBucket", BucketType.ALL_PRIVATE);

//Retrieve an upload URL
B2UploadRequest request = B2API.getUploadURL(session, bucket);

//Upload the file
B2File file = B2API.uploadFile(request, new File("test.txt"), "test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now an official Java SDK for the Backblaze B2 storage API called [`b2-sdk-java`](https://github.com/Backblaze/b2-sdk-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library that i'm developing now.. [AndroidBackBlazeHelper](https://github.com/yorondahacker/AndroidBackBlazeHelper)

```
//TODO replace applicationKey with your key
//TODO replace applicationKeyId with your key
BlazeClient client = new BlazeClient(this,applicationKeyId,applicationKey); 

BlazeFileUploader blazeFileUploader = 
new BlazeFileUploader(  client , bucketId); //TODO replace bucketId with your Bucket Id
blazeFileUploader.startUploading(fileUri, fileName , contentType); // replace the content type with mime type or choose one from FileTypes.class e.g. FileTypes.IMAGE_TYPE
```